# How to populate a new list inside reduce function - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-structures, logic

Reduce function is the first choice to find the total of elements in the Array/List

I want to create an Array of the totals till that index of an array.

So for `[2,1,2,1,2,1,1]` as Input, I am expecting `[2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]` as output

I know the Javascript way, but failing to get it in Kotlin
[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0r26hLfg/)

```
var sumArr = []
var res = intrv.reduce((a,b) => {
     sumArr.push(a+b); 
 return a+b
})
console.log(sumArr)
```

What should be the Kotlin code equivalent

[Kotlin Playground trials](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjcyIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiLyoqXG4gKiBZb3UgY2FuIGVkaXQsIHJ1biwgYW5kIHNoYXJlIHRoaXMgY29kZS4gXG4gKiBwbGF5LmtvdGxpbmxhbmcub3JnIFxuICovXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhciBnZyA9IGFycmF5T2Y8SW50PigyLDEsMiwxLDIsMSwxKVxuICAgIHZhciBtZyA9IG11dGFibGVMaXN0T2Y8SW50PigpXG4gICAgdmFyIGdnQXJyID0gZ2cucmVkdWNlIHthLGIgLT4ge1xuICAgICAgICBtZy5hZGQoYStiKTtcbiAgICAgICAgcmV0dXJuIGErYlxuICAgIH1cbiAgICBwcmludGxuKGdnLmFzTGlzdCgpKVxuICAgIHByaW50bG4obWcpXG59In0=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost 1:1 conversion:

```
var intrv = listOf(0,2,1,2,1,2,1,1)
var sumArr : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
val sum = intrv.reduce { a, b -> sumArr.add(a+b); a + b }
println(sumArr)
```

prints:

```
[2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Neat! Learnings - No braces for lamba body, no return (as last line is default)

Comment: No, I see now @RahulKahale didnt add 0 in the question as the first element, but its in the fiddler js example - and I used fiddler js sample as the source code for conversion to kotlin.

Comment: Yes..I am fine with zero. Reduce needs a starting point of sum... Not an issue. Tricky part was Kotlin syntax.

Comment: Yes, it's not evident. But look at the performance benefit it gives. No slicing in loop needed.

Comment: If it works for you fine, but you did not describe the requirement like that.

Comment: Its outside the box thinking. ;-)

Comment: As I see it it's outside the requirement.

Comment: If you dont want 0 as first element, then I suggest using `fold` as here: https://pl.kotl.in/Uurg29xiH

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is `sliceArray()` and `sum()`:

```
var gg = arrayOf<Int>(2,1,2,1,2,1,1)
val mg = gg.mapIndexed { index, _ ->  gg.sliceArray(0..index).sum() }
println(mg)
```

Will print:

```
[2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

For each item you get a slice of the array from the start up the item's position and sum over that slice.